# On typesetting i.e. and e.g. with a following comma in American English in \nonfrenchspacing

Tags: spacing

Let's assume that you write American English and put commas after “i.e.” and “e.g.”.
[It has long been known](http://courses.washington.edu/passr209/SciJargon.html) that when you have a closing parenthesis after such an abbreviation, as in “Take an arbitrary cat (a Siamese cat, e.g.) and try to understand which kind of fuel it needs.  To this end, …”, you better put a `\@` right after “e.g.” because your sentence may be used in the `\nonfrenchspacing` context and you don't want to have an inter-sentence spacing in the middle of a sentence:

```
Take an arbitrary cat (a Siamese cat, e.g.\@) and try to understand which kind of fuel it needs.  To this end, \ldots.
```

The same goes when you have a closing bracket:

```
Take an arbitrary cat [a Siamese cat, e.g.\@] and try to understand which kind of fuel it needs.  To this end, \ldots.
```

But when “e.g.” is followed by a comma, or a right brace, or an old-style slash bracket, no `\@` is needed; all three choices below produce the same result:

```
To this end, take a can of fuel /gasoline, e.g./ and a funnel.  Then, \ldots.\\

To this end, take a can of fuel /gasoline, e.g.\@/ and a funnel.  Then, \ldots.\\

To this end, take a can of fuel /gasoline, e.g./\ and a funnel.  Then, \ldots.\\
```

I have not tested chevrons, quotation marks, or any other symbols — I have no idea what the result would be.

1. Why is there such a difference when using different symbols after the period?
2. Can you safely write `… , e.g., …` in all contexts in the middle of a sentence or do you need to say `… , e.g.\@, …` (in some circumstances currently unknown to me)? Example:

   ```
   Then, call up the cat, e.g., by saying ``here kitty-kitty.''
   ```

(P.S. The text about cats is absolutely imaginary; don't actually do this.)

Comment: Basically, are you asking why TeX inserts an after-sentence-end space after `)` and `]`, e.g., "Come here. (Yes, now.) Move it." but not after symbols such as `,` say, "..., e.g., ...")?

Comment: @Mico I assume you mean “when a period comes right before the symbol (`)`, `]`, `,`, `/`, `\}`, …)”? I'm even not sure whether TeX does exactly this: taking a look at the next symbol and deciding which space to use. You can imagine, e.g., that we have more than one noncontrol, nonspace, and nonalphanumeric symbol after the period, though I wouldn't know any usage of it. The most common case for me is really the "e.g., ", that is, the comma and the space.

Comment: You may be interested in chapter 20 of [TeX by Topic](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf). In short the spacing is controlled by the spacefactor. Parentheses have spacefactor code 0, which means they are essentially invisible for spacefactor purposes. The `,` has spacefactor code 1000 or 1250, which means that it won't get enlarged spaces (but it might be slightly more stretchable).

Comment: @moewe Thanks. Do you mean that `e.g., ` might be slightly more stretchable than `e.g.\@, `?

Comment: I don't think so, no. `.` has sf code 1000 in French spacing and 3000 in non-French-spacing. `,` has 1000 in French and 1250 in non-French. `\@` just sets the space factor to 1000. In both `e.g., ` and `e.g.\@, ` the rules leave us with the same end space factor (1000 in French, 1250 in non-French; the 1250 is a bit more stretchy than the 1000).

Comment: @moewe Thanks, So, given what you wrote, we can happily write `e.g., ` and `i.e., ` (and, perhaps, `etc., `) without bothering about `\@`, can't we?

Comment: Yes. Unless someone messes with the space factor codes of the characters involved you won't need a `\@` before the comma in those examples.

Comment: @moewe I see, thx! (I could imagine that babel might hypothetically do this, so, if you wish to comment on that, please feel free.)

Comment: As far as I can see core `babel` only sets space factor codes to the 'standard values' Eijkhout lists in *TeX by Topic* (e.g. 1000 in French and 1250 in non-French for the comma). I would expect most languages modules to leave this alone, but I obviously didn't check them all.

Answer (score 10):

When typesetting lines, TeX maintains an internal parameter called `\spacefactor`. The rules are simple:

1. each character has an associated `\sfcode` (an integer);
2. after a character is added to the horizontal list, the `\spacefactor` becomes the `\sfcode` of that character, except in two cases;
3. if the character's `\sfcode` is 0, no change is made to `\spacefactor`;
4. if the current `\spacefactor` is less than 1000 and the new character's `\sfcode` is > 1000, the `\spacefactor` is set to 1000.

The space factor can also be set manually, with the instruction `\spacefactor<integer>` and indeed, LaTeX’s `\@` is an abbreviation for `\spacefactor 1000`.

The normal setting (under `\nonfrenchspacing`) is that

- uppercase letters have `\sfcode` 999;
- closing parentheses, quotes and brackets have `\sfcode` 0;
- punctuation signs (comma, colon, semicolon, period, question mark, exclamation mark) have `\sfcode` larger than 1000 (depending on the “strength” of the punctuation sign);
- every other character has `\sfcode` 1000.

```
the sfcode of ! is 3000
the sfcode of ' is 0
the sfcode of ( is 1000
the sfcode of ) is 0
the sfcode of * is 1000
the sfcode of + is 1000
the sfcode of , is 1250
the sfcode of - is 1000
the sfcode of . is 3000
the sfcode of / is 1000
the sfcode of 0 is 1000
the sfcode of 1 is 1000
the sfcode of 2 is 1000
the sfcode of 3 is 1000
the sfcode of 4 is 1000
the sfcode of 5 is 1000
the sfcode of 6 is 1000
the sfcode of 7 is 1000
the sfcode of 8 is 1000
the sfcode of 9 is 1000
the sfcode of : is 2000
the sfcode of ; is 1500
the sfcode of < is 1000
the sfcode of = is 1000
the sfcode of > is 1000
the sfcode of ? is 3000
the sfcode of @ is 1000
the sfcode of A is 999
[...]
the sfcode of Z is 999
the sfcode of [ is 1000
the sfcode of ] is 0
the sfcode of ` is 1000
the sfcode of a is 1000
[...]
the sfcode of z is 1000
the sfcode of { is 1000
the sfcode of | is 1000
the sfcode of } is 1000
```

Under `\frenchspacing`, punctuation signs have `\sfcode` 1000 and so the `\spacefactor` has no bearing at all.

Indeed, TeX adds some stretchability if a space is found when `\spacefactor` is larger than 1000 and even extra space if it is ≥ 2000. But beware, there's a catch! (There's always a catch, you know.) The primitive command “backslash-space” inserts a space that's not influenced by the current space factor.

The idea of `\nonfrenchspacing` is to obtain larger space after a punctuation sign, but this should not be influenced by quotes or parentheses.

So, with `(Gotcha!)` the space factor after the closing parenthesis would be 3000, exactly as if the parenthesis was missing. Similarly with  ``` ``Gotcha.'' ```.

Typing `e.g.\@,` is redundant and `e.g.,` would have the same effect: in either case the space factor after the comma would be 1250.

The `\@` is important if you *don't* have a comma after `e.g.` so with `e.g.\@` the period would not be considered sentence-ending (no extra space or extra stretching). Hence, in the case of

```
Take an arbitrary cat (a Siamese cat, e.g.\@) and
```

you *do* need `\@`, because `)` is “transparent” to the space factor.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both yours and Mico's answer are great; I have no idea on whom to give the checkmark, as both deserve it.

Comment: In texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/usrguide3.tex we see `etc.\@,`. The way I read your answer, the `\@` in this position is redundant, and the fragment can be safely replaced with `etc.,`. Is this correct, or is “LATEX3 methods for authors” so nonstandard that it really profits from `\@` there?

Comment: @AlMa1r Yes, it's redundant. But it may be a good idea to *always* type `etc.\@`, so you never have to worry about what happens next.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, and when you wish to search for text inside LaTeX documents, the less clutter you have, the easier the search …

Comment: Also recall Lamport's answer to “Three LATEX mistakes that people should stop making?”: “1. Worrying too much about formatting and not enough about content. 2. Worrying too much about formatting and not enough about content. 3. Worrying too much about formatting and not enough about content.” (Source: TUGboat, Volume 22 (2001), No. 1/2.)

Answer (score 4):

Your main question would appear to be about the *why*, not about the *what* or *how*.

The premise is that `\nonfrenchspacing` is in effect, so that TeX is set to insert a bit more whitespace after a sentence-ending period (aka full stop), question mark, and exclamation mark than it'll do for ordinary interword whitespace.

A moment's reflection reveals that -- in English and in many other languages -- an entire sentence can occur inside a pair of (usually round) parentheses. E.g., with apologies to Julius Caesar, consider the following two fragments:

```
  I came. I hesitated.
  (I came.) I hesitated.
```

Thus, if TeX is supposed to insert extra whitespace after "came.", it should also do so after "came.)", right?

To the best of my knowledge, a period, question mark, or exclamation mark that's followed by a non-letter character *other than ), ], and some quotation marks* cannot end a sentence. Hence, TeX should therefore *not* insert extra whitespace after, say, `e.g.,` and `i.e.,`, right?

Does this answer your *why* question? The "how" and "what" issues are explained very nicely in @moewe's comments.

Comment: Thanks, Mico! Well, I agree that “why” questions are tricky, and you nevertheless did the best job of explaining the Why to me in such a way that I understand it.

Comment: Both yours and egreg's answer are great; I have no idea on whom to give the checkmark, as both deserve it.

Comment: In the past times of machines without parentheses (I think, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typewriter#/media/File:Sholes_typewriter.jpg or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typewriter#/media/File:MEK_II-327.jpg), slashes were used instead, and then a slash could end a sentence. I guess, we'd encounter this case if we were to retype an old text exactly as it was typed originally. It'd be a pretty rare use of TeX.

Comment: @GeekestGeek - I suppose you're right. Hence, if one were to implement a TeX-based document setup in which `/` can take the roles of `(` and `)`, one would have to modify the `\sfactor` rules to make `/` "transparent" to the space factor rules. I will confess to never having had to contemplate such a contingency so far... Tsk, tsk.

Comment: I was wrong in interpreting one photo: the robotron example did have parentheses. The old Sholes one did not have ( ). Moreover, some localized machines often do not have ( ), e.g., https://hsto.org/webt/9a/oe/2z/9aoe2z3iegyivp_qt1rlxugqrpu.jpeg . Retyping old texts produced by such localized machines would involve lots of slashes. On the other hand, as these texts are non-English, they typically have neither „i.e.“ nor „e.g.“; however, such texts may have other abbreviations instead. Example: „Кроли — это не только ценный мех, но и /ценные когти, шерсть и т.д./“

Comment: @user224332 The USB connector on the photo is hilarious! An imaginary example could be retyping `Теперь, о кроликах. /Кролики — это не только ценный мех, но и три–четыре килограмма диетического, легкоусвояемого мяса./ Рассмотрим …` produced by the above typing machine with LaTeX. I don't know a good example in English.

Comment: An imaginary English text produced with the old Sholes machine https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Sholes_typewriter.jpg could hypothetically be: `Now, about Caesar. /I came./ I hesitated.` However, I miss the slashes on that machine.